Is there RxJS pipe operator that triggers a new outer observable ("Set it and forget it")?
I am trying to execute a method 1000 milliseconds after all items in pipe finish, and I don't want the result, nor do I want it to change the current value of the pipe. What I have here is what I am doing which works, but it isn't using rxjs completely with the setTimeout.
selectionChanged$ = this.selectionChanged.pipe(
 map(() => this.someValue),
 tap(() => /* do stuff */),
 tap(() => setTimeout(() => this.doSomething(), 1000))
);

I then tried this, but it does two things that I don't want:

It waits for the timer to complete
It changes the final result to a number

doSomething$ = timer(1000).pipe(
  tap(() => this.doSomething()),
);

selectionChanged$ = this.selectionChanged.pipe(
 map(() => this.someValue),
 tap(() => /* do stuff */),
 switchMap(() => this.doSomething$)
);

Is there a way to get the desired result without (aka "Set it and forget it"):

Using subscribe()
Waiting for the timer to complete
Modifying the final result


You could do something like this:
const observable$ = source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(val => timer(delay).pipe(
    tap(() => doSomething()),
    ignoreElements(),
    startWith(val)
  ))
);

The idea here is to create an observable that immediately emits the value (startWith), then after the duration (timer) executes the side effect function.  We use ignoreElements to block emission from the timer.
The benefit here over using setTimeout is that if the consumer unsubscribes, the side effect logic will not be executed.
You could even roll it into a custom operator:
function delayTap<T>(fn: (...args: T[]) => void, delay: number): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return mergeMap(val => timer(delay).pipe(
    tap(() => fn(val)),
    ignoreElements(),
    startWith(val)
  ))
}

const observable$ = source$.pipe(
  delayTap(v => doSomething(v), 1000)
);

Here's a StackBlitz.

Do you mean like this? I use delay of 1000s and then finally using map, set the last emit value to zero.
import './style.css';

import { rx, of, map, fromEvent, tap, timer, delay } from 'rxjs';
const someValue = 'qwerty';

const doSomething = () => {
  console.log('doSomething');
  return 0;
};

fromEvent(window, 'click')
  .pipe(
    map(() => someValue),
    tap<unknown>(() => {
      console.log(Math.random());
    }),
    delay(1000),
    map(() => doSomething())
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

Stackblitz Demo

I guess I didn't mention this, but angular renders some html, and with delay it
delays the rendering of the html. I would like the html to be rendered right away, but the event to run 1 second later. The closest thing I could find is tap(() => asyncScheduler.schedule(this.doSomething, 1000))

@GetOffMyLawn would suggest you create a directive that emits an event on ngafterviewinit, you can put this on html that renders based on the condition, this can be used to execute your logic without timing issues
